# How to Fire all the rules in drools regardless of which group it belongs to

Tags: drools, rule-engine, rule

How to Fire all the rules in drools regardless of which group it belongs to,
I have two Rule-flow groups i.e., "rules1" "rules2", How to fire all the rules without mentioning rule-flow group name? I want to apply all the rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If a rule is in a group, the group has to receive the focus - otherwise the rules won't fire.

However, it isn't difficult at all to add a rule that will set the focus to another group.

Also, you can write a very simple loop setting the focus to group after group and to fire all rules.

If you don't need the grouping, remove the rule attribute.

Comment: What kind of loop do you mean?

Comment: A loop that iterates the list of the rule groups you use. Starts with "for(...".